# Users of Firebase Database to customlistview

Tags: java, android

I have users in my firebase database and I would like to add all the users into my customlistview. How can I do that? I'm confused with this string.

```
String[] names={


            "A 1",
            "B 2",
            "C 3"

    };
```

**My Mainactivity**

```
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;



public class MainActivityCustonlistViewnew extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<UserInfo> userInfos;
    private CustomListAdapter customListAdapter;
    private ListView customListView;



    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

    private  DatabaseReference UserData = databaseReference.child("Users");


    private List<String> friends = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] names={


            "A 1",
            "B 2",
            "C 3"

    };

    private String[] professions={
            "Rank 1",
            "Rank 2",
            "Rank 3"

    };
    private int[] photos={
            R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_6

    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maincustomlistview);
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar));



        customListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.custom_list_view);
        userInfos=new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.sort(names, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        customListAdapter=new CustomListAdapter(userInfos,MainActivityCustonlistViewnew.this);
        customListView.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
        getDatas();
        customListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivityCustonlistViewnew.this, "Name : " + names[i] + "\n Profession : " + professions[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });




    }

    // getting all the datas
    private void getDatas(){




        for(int count=0;count<names.length;count++){

            userInfos.add(new UserInfo(names[count],professions[count],photos[count]));

        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_option,menu);
        MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView=(SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                newText=newText.toString();
                ArrayList<UserInfo> newUserInfos=new ArrayList<>();

                for(UserInfo userInfo:userInfos){
                    String name=userInfo.getName().toLowerCase();
                    String profession=userInfo.getProfession().toLowerCase();
                    if(name.contains(newText) || profession.contains(newText)){
                        newUserInfos.add(userInfo);
                    }
                }
                customListAdapter.filterResult(newUserInfos);
                customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Please see my firebase database
[FirebaseDatabase Users](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/seamans-50d61.appspot.com/o/FCMImages%2FCapture.JPG?alt=media&token=a0e3a9a7-5047-471f-ba3b-9deaf2381834)

Comment: Please provide the code to retrieve users list from firebase

Comment: that is the other problem, i dont know how to do that. hehehe